# Proof for solving linear congruence

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

> Show that the equation $$
>   a x \equiv b \bmod{n} \; \quad a, b \in \mathbb{Z}\, , n \in \mathbb{N}
> $$ with $d:= \gcd(a,n)$ has no solution if $d \nmid b$. But if $d \mid b$, it is equivalent to $$
>   x \equiv y \frac{b}{d} \bmod{\frac{n}{d}}
> $$ with $y\in \mathbb{Z}$ chosen so, that $y a + z n = d$ for a $z \in \mathbb{Z}$.

*Proof:* $d \nmid b \Rightarrow d \nmid (a x - b) \Rightarrow n \nmid (a x - b)$, so there can be no solution.

Now $d \mid b$, then Bézout's identity guarantees the existence of $y$. Also we see that $$a x \equiv b \bmod{n} \Leftrightarrow \frac{a}{d} x \equiv \frac{b}{d} \bmod{\frac{n}{d}}\, .$$

Since $\frac{a}{d}$ and $\frac{n}{d}$ are coprime, $\frac{a}{d} \in \Bigl(\mathbb{Z}/\bigl(\frac{n}{d}\bigr)\mathbb{Z}\Bigr)^{\times}$ and its inverse is obviously $y$.

Multiplication with the unit $y$ is injective (this is in general not true for all elements — the ring might not be an integral domain), which means the following equations are equivalent:
$$\frac{a}{d} x \equiv \frac{b}{d} \bmod{\frac{n}{d}} \Leftrightarrow y \frac{a}{d} x \equiv y \frac{b}{d} \bmod{\frac{n}{d}}\, .$$ With $y\frac{a}{d} \equiv 1 \bmod{\frac{n}{d}}$ we're done. $\square$

---

Could you please check if my proof is correct? Thank you!

Comment: $d\nmid(ax-b)\Rightarrow n\nmid(ax-b)$ is true but not that trivial so I think better show it (but using contraposition makes it trivial). Otherwise I think that your proof is correct.

Comment: Thank you! You overlooked a small detail... I wrote $y\frac{a}{d} = 1$, that was not correct.

Comment: You're welcome. $y\times\dfrac{a}{d}=1$ is also correct if we consider $\times$ the binary operation of the ring $(\mathbb{Z}/\left(\dfrac{n}{d}\right)\mathbb{Z},+,\times)$.